# C - Confused by 'control may reach end of non-void function' when using certain if/else syntax

Tags: c, function, if-statement

When defining a function in C, I receive a 'control may reach end of non-void function' error in the compiler when writing the if/else logic a certain way (Scenario 1 below), but I do not receive the error when writing the logic another way (Scenario 2 below). To me, both ways of writing this function seem similar, so I am at a loss as to why version 1 won't compile.

**Scenario 1**

```
bool search(int value, int values[], int n)
{
    int i;
    if (n<1)
        {
            return false;
        }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if (value==values[i])
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
           return false; 
        }
    }

}
```

**Scenario 2**

```
bool search(int value, int values[], int n)
{
    int i;
    if (n<1)
        {
            return false;
        }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if (value==values[i])
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false; 
}
```

Won't Scenario 2 always return false after the for loop? Or does the function essentially 'Stop' after returning a value for the first time, therefore returning 'true' once value matches values[i]?

Comment: In scenario 1, all of your `return` statements are in conditional blocks.  Thus the compiler sees this and gives you a warning.

Comment: The two scenarios are doing different things. Scenario 1 the compiler is not smart enough to know that the for loop is not actually going to be used as when i=0 one or the other returns is going to be used

Comment: The function exits when it executes a `return`, so the second example won't execute the `return false;` at the end if it hit one of the other `return`s first.

Comment: In the second example, the `if (n < 1) {...}` part is actually unnecessary, since if `n` is less than `1` the `for` loop wouldn't run (it's test would be false), and you'd skip over it to the `return false;` at the end anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that C compiler is not smart enough to figure out that there is no scenario when the first function would reach the end without returning a value:

- When the loop executes at least once, there is a conditional return from both branches of the if statement, and
- When the loop never executes, there is going to be a return from the conditional statement at the top of the function.

C standard does not require such checks, so the compiler issues a warning.

Comment: *That is also why the compiler misses the fact that the last return statement of your second code is never reached.* - This is not true - consider when value is not in the array.

Comment: @EdHeal Oops, you're right, I missed the fact that the `else` branch is not there in the second code snippet. My phone screen is too small for that :-) Thank you!

Comment: Thank you both for the answers - this makes a lot of sense. I realize now having the false return in the 'else' statement within the loop would just return false on the first run-through unless of course it luckily found the value in the array[0]